# Replace function in Python is not working (other answers did not solve my problem)

Tags: python, pandas

I know it is a repeated question, but I tried the answers from other questions and I could not solve the issue.

In summary, I want to replace 0 by 'A A ', 1 by 'A B ', 2 by 'B B ', and 5 by '0 0 '.

My impute datafile (datafile.txt) format is presented below, and I want to replace just information in the column "Geno" (in the true dataset I have a million lines).

| Sample | Geno |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | 11010111151 |
| ID2 | 12000120022 |
| ID3 | 12055520022 |
| ID4 | 12000120022 |

The pipeline I am using is:

```
import pandas as pd
#input file
fin = pd.read_table('dataframe.txt',sep = ' ', header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(fin)
geno = (df.iloc[: , 1:])
id = (df.iloc[: , 0])
geno = pd.DataFrame(geno)
geno2 = geno.replace("0","A A ").replace("1","A B ").replace("2","B B ").replace("5","0 0 ")
```

I appreciate your help! I was doing it in bash (using awk), but it is taking a long time. I decided to try in Python since I believe would be faster. PS: I am beginner in Python.
Thank you again.

Comment: Do not use `id` as a variable, please. It is a built-in function. You can use `df_id`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will avoid it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY:

```
df.Geno = df.Geno.astype(str).str.replace("0","A A ").str.replace("1","A B ").str.replace("2","B B ").str.replace("5","0 0 ")
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Sample                                          Geno
0    ID1  A B A B A A A B A A A B A B A B A B 0 0 A B 
1    ID2  A B B B A A A A A A A B B B A A A A B B B B 
2    ID3  A B B B A A 0 0 0 0 0 0 B B A A A A B B B B 
3    ID4  A B B B A A A A A A A B B B A A A A B B B B
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. Just to understand, I have to add the "astype(str).str" to work, correct? How was the Python reading my file? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pythonlearner you could run `print(df.dtypes)` to see what the datatypes of your columns are. `Geno` was `int64`.

Answer (score 2):

[Series Replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace) with a `dict` is also an option:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sample': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4'],
    'Geno': [11010111151, 12000120022, 12055520022, 12000120022]
})

df['Geno'] = df['Geno'].astype(str).replace({
    '0': ' A A',
    '1': ' A B',
    '2': ' B B',
    '5': ' 0 0'
}, regex=True).str.lstrip()

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
  Sample                                          Geno
0    ID1   A B A B A A A B A A A B A B A B A B 0 0 A B
1    ID2   A B B B A A A A A A A B B B A A A A B B B B
2    ID3   A B B B A A 0 0 0 0 0 0 B B A A A A B B B B
3    ID4   A B B B A A A A A A A B B B A A A A B B B B
```

Comment: Thank you very much!